# Property 'render' does not exist on type 'typeof __React'

Tags: typescript, reactjs

When compiling script

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
import React = __React;

var content = <div>Hello, world!</div>;

React.render(content, document.getElementById('output'));
```

I get an error

`$ tsc --jsx react app.tsx
app.tsx(6,7): error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'typeof __React'.`

Is there any way to fix it? 
Thanks

Comment: If you are using React >=0.14, the `render` method is now part of `react-dom` package https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `import React = __React;`

Please use `import React = require('react')` ... but this is not the source of your error

> `React.render(content, document.getElementById('output'));`

Please use `ReactDOM.render(` instead of `React.render`. Get react-dom as `import ReactDOM = require('react-dom')`. This is needed with react `0.14`.

Alternatively get the *old definitions for React*.

Comment: *Thank you* for the thank you. Also please mark as answered :)